# I cant get civi Bounce Processing or Email-to-Activity Processing to function.

Tags: civimail

Where can I find help? I am willing to pay a developer to teach me

Comment: It is usually helpful to others if you flesh our your question, explain what you have tried, where you have researched etc. For example, have you read http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/.

Comment: And if you want professional support, there is a list of developers here you could try if you don't get a response through here directly https://civicrm.org/providers

Answer (score 2):

You should read: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/

After reading you can ask specific questions here on StackExchange.

If you want to find an expert: https://civicrm.org/providers or use http://civi911.com (Disclosure: I work for AGH Strategies who offer this service)